# Can't access MEANJS application in local virtaulbox from outside

Tags: node.js, virtualbox, meanjs

I setup a virtual box in my local Windows 7 OS, the guest OS is CentOS.

I am using NAT, and I added the port forwarding rules in the Network settings.

After I started the application, I tried in the CentOS as localhost: 3000, and I can access the webpage.

However, when I tried localhost: 38888 and 127.0.0.1:38888 or 0.0.0.0:38888 in my Windows7, I can't access the application.

I tried start the nginx in the guest OS and added a rule for forwaring host's port to guest's port, and I can access it.

Does anyone know why?

I can't post the screenshot of the port forwarding rule, so I will explain at here:
I added a rule named rule which is using TCP protocal, and it is forwarding from host's port 38888 to guest's 3000

Answer (score 0):

At last, I changed the MEAN.JS application's startup port as 80 (obviously this is not a good practice), and it works.

My guess is the VM's guest OS blocks the request to other port. I will go some deep investigation.